# How do I remove unused dependencies in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I find out the dependencies in Cargo.toml that are unused? How can I remove them automatically?

Comment: It seems like https://github.com/est31/cargo-udeps and/or https://github.com/Bromeon/cargo-machete are your best bets

Comment: Looks like cargo-machete is gone now.

Comment: You can use this [cargo-machete](https://github.com/bnjbvr/cargo-machete) crate instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One option is to use [cargo-udeps](https://github.com/est31/cargo-udeps).

You can install it via command:

```bash
cargo install cargo-udeps --locked
```

Then, to find unused dependencies in production target:

```bash
cargo +nightly udeps
```

To find unused dev dependencies:

```bash
cargo +nightly udeps --all-targets
```